# EF6 error: The specified metadata path is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been building a new query with entity framework using c#

```
Core.Presenze_Timbratore pt1 = db.Presenze_Timbratore
           .Where(q => q.Badge == txtBadge.Text && q.Data==oggi)
           .OrderByDescending(q=>q.Ora)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

But it throws error when running.

> Error: "The specified metadata path is not valid. A valid path must
>   be either an existing directory, an existing file with extension
>   '.csdl', '.ssdl', or '.msl', or a URI that identifies an embedded
>   resource."

Anyone has any idea if the code is wrong or what could possibily be the mistake?

Comment: Have you moved your edmx model without changing your connectionstring? Or have you done anything else to the connection string or edmx model?

Comment: I have moved the model to a different project.

Comment: IT is says that your connection string metadata paths are wrong, check them

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to fix this is to remove your connection string and open the edmx updater and supply a new connection string when asked.

Comment: I've removed the connection string but it wont add the new connection string.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project, it will solve the issue.

Comment: Silvermind, it worked! thanks.